# Getting camera instance in Sony xperia

Tags: android, android-camera

I have developed an application, that captures image by its front camera, using a surface view. It is working fine on other phones except Sony phones.
The log cat for Sony phone says

> *Permission failure*:**com.sonyericsson.permission.CAMERA_EXTENDED**

I have included this permission also, but its not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: u add these permission     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera">

Comment: yes I have added this feature and also this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

Comment: instead of using user_permission use user_feature and try once

Comment: I have added both and its working fine in other phones. I don't know why it is creating problem in Sony Phones.

Answer (score 1):

This permission failure is only a warning; it may prevent using higher resolutions, though. Try 320x240 to begin with, and post more information if this attempt fails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting this Permission failure as soon as I call Camera.open(); and also when I call Camera.Parameters parameter = camera.getParameters();
Where camera is an object of Camera.

Comment: But I will try what you have told and tell you what was the result.

Comment: Still not able to capture image from sony phone.
Still getting the same Permission failure.

Comment: Are you trying to capture through ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448731/does-samsung-galaxy-siii-have-a-bug-in-its-camera for a similar problem!

Comment: No I'm using the `SurfaceView`.
Before starting the preview, I try to initialize my object of Camera class and while trying to do this I get that Permission failure.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are working with the new camera HAL introduced in API 21:

I had the same issue for my Sony Xperia Z4 Tablet. The Problem for me was, that i was configuring the flash (to light the scene) with

`CaptureRequest.Builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);`

This device has no builtin flash, so after removing this it worked fine.
I got the same logcat output as you had.