# Does Samsung Galaxy SIII have a bug in its camera?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I use the following code to kick off the camera, however, 3/4's of the time, the photo does not save to memory. This only occurs on the Galaxy SIII. It works on the Nexus S and Nexus One

```
public void photoNew() {
    holdingImage = getContentResolver().insert(MUtil.genImgUri(), new ContentValues());   
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putParcelable(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, holdingImage);
    extras.putBoolean("return-data", true);
    i.putExtras(extras);
    startActivityForResult(i, REQ_PHOTO);   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a well known bug with different Samsung devices that do not support EXTRA_* with camera intent, see

http://thanksmister.com/2012/03/16/android_null_data_camera_intent/

http://kevinpotgieter.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/null-intent-passed-back-on-samsung-galaxy-tab/

Comment: ill investigate shortly. Glad you actually knew about this tidbit!

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248265/camera-intent-not-working-with-samsung-galaxy-s3/15287164#15287164