# File Chooser not works in Samsung Tab 3 Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an webview with file chooser which is works in `Samsung Galaxy Tab 2(Android 4.1.1), Lenovo, Nexus Tablets`. But the problem is it is not woking in `Samsung galaxy Tab 3`. Which is the `Android 4.4 tablet`. I added my `setWebChromeClient` code here. Can you Please someone help me.

```
// implement WebChromeClient inner class
        // we will define openFileChooser for select file from camera
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                    String acceptType) {
                /** updated, out of the IF **/
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                /** updated, out of the IF **/
                Log.e("Reac", "**Here");
                try {
                    File imageStorageDir = new File(base_directory,
                            "profile_pictures");
                    if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                        imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                    }
                    src_file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator
                            + "IMG_" + child_id + ".jpg");
                    mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(src_file); // save to the
                                                                // private
                                                                // variable

                    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            mCapturedImageURI);

                    startActivityForResult(captureIntent,
                            FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:" + e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }



            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            // openFileChooser for other Android versions
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                    String acceptType, String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }

            /** Added code to clarify chooser. **/

            // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a console message
            // informing what action to perform, taking a photo or updating the
            // file
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
                onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
                return true;
            }

            public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber,
                    String sourceID) {
                // Log.d("androidruntime", "Per cÔøΩnsola: " + message);
            }
            /** Added code to clarify chooser. **/

        });
```

I added only piece of code. Please ask me if any details required.

Comment: can you show the logcat error?

Comment: There is nothing in the error log. Once click file chooser button then no action trigger ..

Comment: Then have a look at the links posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448731/does-samsung-galaxy-siii-have-a-bug-in-its-camera

Comment: What is the relationship between my code and in this link?

Comment: I think it's an issue with the implementation of Android in certain samsung devices.

Comment: How can i solve this?

Comment: Can you put some logs here..

Answer (score 5):

It seems there is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220) in Android 4.4 that make `<input type="file">` not work inside a WebView.

Unfortunately `openFileChooser` is not a public API and there is not a public support for that.
In Android Lollipop has been introduced the API [onShowFileChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback<android.net.Uri[]>,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams)) for this purpose.

My suggest is to workaround the problem using the [JavaScript native WebView interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) and define a custom openFileChooser API handled by the native part of your App.

Comment: If i try to use javascript native webview interface then how to get input for this method  public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                    String acceptType) {?

Comment: The idea is to completely workaround the standard file chooser behavior by: 1: Having a button on web part that call the injected javascript API "openFile". 2: Handle the openFile on native part by launching an intent to pick up a file. 3: Handle on native parte the onActivityResult resolving the path of the file choose. 4: Send the path to the Web part by a custom JavaScript API (e.g. webView.evaluateJavaScript("selectedFile("path") ", null); 5: Handle on Web part the logic with the file selected. You may need to change some WebView settings as WebSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs

Comment: Hi do u got any solution. i have same problem with samsung tab 3.please post your answer if you got solution